# $http get script with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

there is a script that i want to perrform but i want to ask you something about it.Here is the problem:

I have A and B pages.
(A---->B) According to the searching criterias in A page,it goes to B page  in a way of Form Get and brings back Json data. But as Json data comes back to B page, it can't get this data and bind in B page.

When i practise this whole process in page A, in the same way i can get json data in page A and bind them.

```
$http.get('/B/?' + "destination=" + xxx )
 .then(function(result) {
   $scope.data = result.data;
});
```

But in page B, i want to bind json data which goes to A-->B and comes back.How can i do this by using AngularJs. You can see this script by searching hotels in [www.expedia.com](http://www.expedia.com) . Actually what i exactly want to do is available in configuration of expedia's hotel search.

Thank you.

Comment: You need a factory to do that

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, what you want is to have 2 applications (2 ng-app, one on page A and one on page B) and share data using Angular.

This is not directly possible with Angular. Angular is about one page that manage the DOM. But it can have different views (see $route).

This is however possible if you pull data from the server in page A to get the result from page B once you are back to A.

What expedia seems to do is post from page A, receive data on page B and show it on page B.